# Get user access token in a console application

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I am writing two applications which communicate with the facebook servers. The first one is an ASP .NET application which gets an access token for the user and another console application which runs on a schedule and gets some data from the server. My issue is how to send the access token to the console application since I cannot get a user access token from a pure C# application right?

Answer (score -2):

There are many ways to pass data between applications. You can use database, file system if your applications are running on one server. You can also try web service, wcf service or web api in distributed systems.

Comment: That doesn't answer his question at all.